# how does promise and useState really work in React with AWS Amplify?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, aws-amplify

I have been following this tutorial to create a React app with AWS Amplify.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-five/

At some point, the following snippet to retrieve the signed urls of images is present.

```
async function fetchNotes() {
  const apiData = await API.graphql({ query: listNotes });
  const notesFromAPI = apiData.data.listNotes.items;
  await Promise.all(notesFromAPI.map(async note => {
    if (note.image) {
      const image = await Storage.get(note.image);
      note.image = image;
    }
    return note;
  }))
  setNotes(apiData.data.listNotes.items);
}
```

My question is, how does the React app retrieve the urls? From my understanding the `.map` function retrieves a new Javascript array which is not stored in a variable when awaited in the `await.Promise.all()` part. The state in `setNotes` is updated with the const apiData, so the notes in `apiData` should not be able to change inplace.

I would appreciate if anyone can share some light on how the shared snippet works.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct when you say that `.map` returns a new array.  However, the objects inside the new array are **not** new.  They are the original objects in the `notesFromAPI` array.  This is because JavaScript passes arrays and objects by [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript/).

This is why you're seeing the `note.image` updated in the original array.  It's the same note object being operated on.

Here's a quick example highlighting what's happening.  As you can see, we're comparing the object received in the `.map` to the original object, and we're seeing they are the same object.

```
let people = [{name: 'Alice', age: 21}, {name: 'Bob', age: 22}];

people.map((person, i) => {
    console.log(person === people[i]); // true
})
```

An easier way to write that snippet, avoiding mutating the original objects, might be something like the following:

```
async function fetchNotes() {
  const { data } = await API.graphql({ query: listNotes });
  const notesFromAPI = data.listNotes.items;
  
  // The resolved array is a new array with new objects.  Mutating either
  // will not mutate the original array or objects.
  const notesWithImages = await Promise.all(notesFromAPI.map(async note => {
    let image = null
    if (note.image) {
      image = await Storage.get(note.image);
    }

    // Make a shallow copy of the note, and add the image to the new object.
    // The original objects in `notesFromAPI` are not modified
    return { ...note, image };
  }))

  // Now we can set the notes to the new array, along with the new objects.
  setNotes(notesWithImages);
}
```

If you were to console.log your `notesFromAPI` array, you'd see that they remain unchanged.

Comment: That really explains it, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> await Promise.all(notesFromAPI.map(async note => {
>     if (note.image) {
>       const image = await Storage.get(note.image);
>       note.image = image;
>     }
>     return note;
>   }))
> ```

Here you are taking your array of notes, and checking if the property `.image` of each note is `true`. If it is, it retrieves the note image from the Storage and attaches it to the note.

You need `Promise.all()`, since to retrieve the note image you need to make an async call, so `.map()` returns an array of `Promises` now and before to return your updated notes array you must make sure that all the notes have been updated so all of your `Promises` have to be in "Resolved" status. 
That's what `Promise.all()` does, it returns another `Promise` that resolves when **all** of the promises passed have resolved and returns an array with all the values returned by each one of the promises it waited for ( Your updated notes ).

Comment: Does that mean that `NotesFromApi` is updated in place? I thought one would need something like `const updatedNotes = await Promise.all(....)`

Comment: Who wrote that code used the "mutability" concept of JS Objects, basically when he  write note.image = image , he is effectively changing the image property of the note of the original notesFromAPI array. This approach is not a good approach usually since it's always better working with immutability and not using original objects reference to avoid subtle bugs and issues, but it works. @HMilbradt showed you an immutable approach, the only issue with that approach is if your note object has nested objects, that way spread operator used like that will keep the reference to those nested objects.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, this does clarify the usage